# package glossaries: acronymstyle using footnote affects main-glossary?

Tags: glossaries

I have two seperate glossaries. One for acronyms and one for general explanations (main).

For acronyms i used the footnote-style. This works as expected: one first use of the acronym a footnote is displayed.

For general explanations i prefer a link to the glossary (no footnote). But there seems to be a problem. On first occurrence, the explanation isn't shown as a link. Maybe the footnote-style of acronyms is interfering...

**Question:** How can i modify the given code to link the explanation to the glossary on first occurrence (...and make all explanations shown in italic)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, shortcuts, acronyms]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries 

\setacronymstyle{footnote-sc}

%% List of Acronyms
\newacronym{IOM}{IOM}{Institute Of Medicine} 

%% List of Explanations
\newglossaryentry{leukemia}{name={leukemia}, plural={leukemia} ,
description={A group of cancers that usually begins in the bone marrow}}

\begin{document}

\ac{IOM} \ac{IOM} \ac{IOM} \\                                                % Works correctly
\gls{leukemia} \gls{leukemia} \gls{leukemia}                 % First occurrence of leukemia isn't linked to glossary


\printnoidxglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossary]
\printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype, nogroupskip, title=Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

[image: leukemia isn't linked when used the first time]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "make all explanations shown in italic"? Do you mean you want the descriptions in the glossary italic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footnote acronym styles do indeed change the `hyperfirst` setting. From the ["Predefined Acronym Styles"](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:predefinedacrstyles) section of the manual:

> In order to avoid nested hyperlinks on first use the footnote styles
>   automatically implement hyperfirst=false for the acronym lists.

You can however override this using `\glshyperfirsttrue` to switch on the first use hyperlinks for all the glossaries. If you also use `\glsacrfootnotetrue`, the first use hyperlinks will only be on for the non-acronym glossaries. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, shortcuts, acronyms]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries 

\setacronymstyle{footnote-sc}

\glshyperfirsttrue
\glsacrfootnotetrue

%% List of Acronyms
\newacronym{IOM}{IOM}{Institute Of Medicine} 

%% List of Explanations
\newglossaryentry{leukemia}{name={leukemia}, plural={leukemia} ,
description={A group of cancers that usually begins in the bone
marrow}}

\begin{document}

\ac{IOM} \ac{IOM} \ac{IOM}

\gls{leukemia} \gls{leukemia} \gls{leukemia}


\printnoidxglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossary]
\printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype, nogroupskip,
title=Abbreviations]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]